# How to call queryForTable to reload data from Parse cloud in PFQueryTableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController` table, which is getting info from parse database. When user select a row it goes to another VC. In that VC user delete some data in Parse table. This Parse table is the same table I have loaded my  `PFQueryTableViewController`. Therefore, I do not need these deleted data to be shown.

When user press back button, this method in `PFQueryTableViewController` get called:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super objectsWillLoad];

}
```

I have checked line by line. It is reloading data but it is not calling:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    return query;
}
```

I deleted some data in the VC and dose not exist on the cloud. But when I press back button it exist. However, when I refresh the table, deleted data will be vanished!

I read documentation [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/loadObjects:clear:) but I can't find how I can call `queryForTable` method to connect to cloud and read data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call this

```
[self loadObjects];
```

instead of

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```