# Dynamic viewForHeaderInSection and multiple cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm trying to make a custom cell to be the Section of my cells:

[image]

For this I'm overriding some functions like:

> numberOfRowsInSection
>
> viewForHeaderInSection
>
> heightForHeaderInSection

And I'm working with multiple `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm using a `if indexPath.row` to identify the `Cell` and populate them in a dynamic way.

```
import UIKit

class TesteTableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {


override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadCollectionViewData()

}


func loadCollectionViewData() {

    // Build a parse query object
    let query = PFQuery(className:"Feed")

    // Check to see if there is a search term


    // Fetch data from the parse platform
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        // The find succeeded now rocess the found objects into the countries array
        if error == nil {

            print(objects!.count)
            // reload our data into the collection view


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

        }
    }
}


override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return objects!.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2")! as! TesteTableViewCell


    return header
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30.0
}


// Initialise the PFQueryTable tableview
override init(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, className: className)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    // Configure the PFQueryTableView
    self.parseClassName = "Feed"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = false
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

var cell: TesteTableViewCell!
    let object = objects![indexPath.section]
if indexPath.row == 0 {
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TesteTableViewCell




// Extract values from the PFObject to display in the table cell
if let nameEnglish = object["name"] as? String {
cell?.label1?.text = nameEnglish

}


}
else{
cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TesteTableViewCell


    // Extract values 2from the PFObject to display in the table cell
    if let nameEnglish2 = object["brief"] as? String {
        cell?.label2?.text = nameEnglish2


    }

}

return cell
}

}
```

With my code I have this result:

[image]

I'm successfully populating both Cells with different Identifiers.

But look like this function is called before the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and it return the content that I have in the storyBoard and not the content that I'm populating dynamically.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2")! as! TesteTableViewCell


    return header
}
```

And I really think that is my problem. (The order that things happen).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want the tableview to refresh itself after you get the data, have the tableview call reloadData, by saying something like `self.tableView.reloadData()` but there are other things in your code that don't make sense to me. You seem to have a lot of stuff in comments that you have yet to implement. You are only returning 1 row for each section. Is that intentional?

Comment: I've used `loadObjects()` instead of `self.tableView.reloadData()`because I'm using Parse framework and it didn't solution the problem, yes it is intentional because I want the simulate the Instagram feed feature

Comment: loadObjects() get the data. self.tableView.reloadData() tell's the tableView that there's new data to be displayed, and it should update itself. You should look for tutorials on how to use uitableview. Your questions are too broad to be covered in a stackoverflow question.

Comment: Looks like you didn't know what you are saying or simple didn't read the entire question, here is a example [Post Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409461/how-to-call-queryfortable-to-reload-data-from-parse-cloud-in-pfquerytableviewcon), please read the entire question before answer anything, anyway thanks in advance.

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you call loadObjects()? See this comment "         // reload our data into the collection view" You need to implement this. If you want to use the convenance functions provided by parse, then do, but don't tag uitableview and only ask about uitableview if your question is really about PFQueryTableViewController

Comment: Marcelo, por que vc está delegando a implementação do viewForHeaderInSection para o dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the code which you have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for `row != 0` because that block of code is never executed which is causing static data rendering from storyboard instead of dynamic data.

In this case you have to give dynamic data to cell in `viewForHeaderInSection` method so that you cell will populate that information on each reload.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2")! as! TesteTableViewCell
let object = objects![section]
 if let nameEnglish2 = object["brief"] as? String {
        header.label2?.text = nameEnglish2
    }
    return header
}
```

Comment: Perfect, now I see where I misunderstood the concept, thanks for the explanation.